# How to tell if Shift is being pressed in a MouseDown event?

Tags: winforms, events

I am catching a `MouseDown` event on a control, which gives me a `MouseEventArgs` object in the signature. Now I want to be able to tell if the user was holding down the "Shift" or "Control" key when they clicked. But the `MouseEventArgs` object doesn't contain any keyboard information!

What's the easiest way of telling whether the keyboard <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys were being held at the time of the click?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the Control.ModifierKeys property to see what's pressed.  For example:

```
    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control) {
            Console.WriteLine("Ctrl+Click");
        }
    }
```

Other modifiers are `Keys.Alt` and `Keys.Shift`.  Find combinations with, say, `(Keys.Control | Keys.Shift)`.

Comment: Since it's a bitwise-flag enum (i.e. can be multiple values at once), you might want `Control.ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control)` -- this will provide `true` if _CTRL+<ANYTHING>_ are pressed.

Comment: Not so advisable, the user will expect something else to happen when he uses, say, Ctrl+Shift+Click.

Comment: Hence the _"might"_ in my comment ;)  I missed the bottom of your answer, though, re: "find combinations with..."

Answer (score 5):

In C#, you can check using -

```
Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) or key.RightShift
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key.aspx