# Run when when you ctrl + click a button in a WinForm?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I'm trying to run a different code when a user hold down the ctrl button and clicks on the NotifyIcon.

My code doesn't work, but I feel it clearly explains when I'm trying to do. This is under a Mouse Click Event.

```
        Private Sub NotifyIcon_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon.MouseClick
        If (e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
            MsgBox("CTRL was pressed !")
        Else
            MsgBox("CTRL was not pressed !")
        End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: Does it say the control key wasn't pressed, or do you not get anything altogether?

Comment: first off `e.Modifiers == Keys.Control` oh wait, its VB, sorry I saw the c# tag first

Comment: @Landmine take a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701830/how-to-tell-if-shift-is-being-pressed-in-a-mousedown-event

Just change Shift with Control

Comment: Is `NotifyIcon` a button? To me it seems like a `NotifyIcon` is a `NotifyIcon`. Also, this question shouldn't have a C# tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not well versed in VB, but you tagged this as C# as well, should be trivial for you to switch over.

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control) {
        Console.WriteLine("Ctrl+Click");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I tagged it as C# as converting the code to and from is as you said, trivial. Thank you, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

A generic method not reliant on MouseEventArgs:

```
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
                ...
            Else
                ...
            End If
```

You can also check for Alt, Shift....

Comment: `ModifierKeys` does not rely on `MouseEventArgs`... It's from `Control` which can be changed for `this` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular `Click` event to read `ModifierKeys`, you don't need the MouseClick event.
Also remember that `Control`, `Shift` and `Alt` are treated as `Flags`. If you don't use them as `Flags`, when user clicks over button holding simultaneously Shift and Control, you won't notice. These 3 options triggers when user holds both buttons:

```
if (ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Shift))
if (ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control))
if (ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Shift) && ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control))
```

This option only triggers when user holds only `Shift` key:

```
if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
```